# Python Tkinter Apply Filter to Text

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple text widget made with Tkinter and Python 3, like this:

```
from tkinter import *
def makeUpper():
    pass
root = Tk()
T = Text(root)
T.pack()
menubar = Menu(root)
menubar.add_command(label="Make Upper", command=makeUpper)
root.config(menu=menubar)
```

When the user selects Make Upper, I would like to make the selected text uppercase.

Comment: What problem are you having doing this? Methods for getting and setting the text in a widget are well documented, as are methods for converting python strings to uppercase.

Comment: @BryanOakley If the text is `Hello World!`, if the user had selected `o Worl`, I would like the button to change the text to `HellO WORLd!`.

Comment: Ok, so what problem are you having? The methods for getting the selected text are well documented. The methods for converting strings to uppcase is documented. The methods for replacing text in a text widget are well documented. After reading the documentation, what have you tried and what don't you understand?